# Imprimir combinações de inteiros em ordem crescente

Tags: java, combinações, array

"Dados dois número inteiros não-negativos m e n, gere todas as combinações de tamanho m dos inteiros de 0 a n-1, na ordem crescente.

Exemplo: m=3 e n=5

(0 1 2); (0 1 3); (0 1 4); (0 2 3); (0 2 4); (0 3 4); (1 2 3); (1 2 4); (1 3 4); (2 3 4)"

Eu não sei como resolver este exercício. O máximo que consegui foi criar o vetor 0 1 2. Percebi que preciso adicionar 1 ao último elemento até que ele atinja o valor n-1, depois pego o vetor 0 1 2 novamente e acrescento 1 aos dois últimos elementos, depois só ao último e assim por diante. Mas não sei como fazer isso. Pensei em usar um FOR para cada rodada de somas, mas no caso a quantidade de FORs dependeria do valor de m e o algoritmo deve servir para quaisquer valores de m e n, pelo que entendi.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n, m, i, j;
        Scanner ent = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite o valor de m:");
        m = ent.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite o valor de n:");
        n = ent.nextInt(); 
        int [] v = new int [m];
        for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
            v[i] = i;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode resolver seu problema utilizando recursividade, segue uma classe em Java adaptada [desse link](http://javafree.uol.com.br/topic-853554-COMBINACOES-POSSIVEIS-DE-25-NUMEROS.html).

```
public class Combinacao {

    private int numeros[];
    private int posicoes;
    private int resultado[];
    private int quantidadeCombinacoes;

    public Combinacao(int m, int n) {
        numeros = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            numeros[i] = i;
        }
        posicoes = m;
        resultado = new int[posicoes];
        quantidadeCombinacoes = 0;
    }

    private void combinar(int inicio, int fim, int profundidade) {
        if ((profundidade + 1) >= posicoes) {
            for (int x = inicio; x <= fim; x++) {
                resultado[profundidade] = numeros[x];
                quantidadeCombinacoes++;
                System.out.print("(");
                for (int i = 0; i < posicoes; i++) {
                    System.out.printf("%d%s", resultado[i], (i == posicoes - 1) ? "" : " ");
                }
                System.out.print("); ");
            }
        } else {
            for (int x = inicio; x <= fim; x++) {
                resultado[profundidade] = numeros[x];
                combinar(x + 1, fim + 1, profundidade + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public void imprimirCombinacoes() {
        combinar(0, numeros.length - posicoes, 0);
    }

    public int getQuantidadeCombinacoes() {
        return quantidadeCombinacoes;
    }
}
```

Para utilizar faça o seguinte:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Combinacao combinacao = new Combinacao(3, 5);
    combinacao.imprimirCombinacoes();
    System.out.println("\nTotal de combinacoes: " + combinacao.getQuantidadeCombinacoes());
}
```

A classe Combinacao recebe depois parâmetros no construtor, esses parâmetros são respectivamente m e n, conforme está na sua pergunta.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda. O único problema é que não entendi... Eu sei apenas o básico do básico. Pelo que aprendi até o momento (que é o que a professora espera encontrar na resposta), devo utilizar laços FOR e variáveis auxiliares. Vou postar na pergunta o código que tenho até agora.

Comment: @CristianeDosSantosCosta, como eu era novo aqui, não tinha opção para comentar, então tive que responder, o código que te passei foi baseado no link que está na resposta, se eu encontrar ou conseguir fazer com FOR edito a resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigada!